# Conditional Expectation of dice rolls

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation, dice

A 6-sided die is rolled for 10 times.  The die rolls are mutually independent.  Each die uniformly likely to result in a digit from 1,2, 3, 4, 5, and 6.  Let X denote the sum of the first 6 rolls and Y denote the sum of the last six rolls.

Find E(X|Y).

I have found E(X), E(Y), Var(X), Var(Y), Cov(X,Y), and Corr(X,Y).

I wish I had input, but am relatively new to statistics and don't know where to start on this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is $E(X)$?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, since only 10 rolls. For example if $X=36$ then $Y$ counts rolls 5,6,7,8,9,10 so is at least $2.$

Comment: $E(X)$ means expected value. In this problem $E(X|Y=k)$ would need to be computed for each of the six possible values of $Y$ separately. That is (I *think*) $E(X|Y)$ is a distribution of the various $E(X|Y=k)$ for $k \in \{1, \cdots, 6 \}.$

Comment: @coffeemath Wouldn't $k$ have 31 possible values ranging from $6$ up to $36$ as its the sum of six dice?

Comment: @IanMiller You're definitely right. If only one could revise comments...

Comment: I too wasn't 100% sure on th meaning of $E(X|Y)$ but if it is meant to be the distribution then working out 31 values is going to be fiddly, long and boring.

Comment: @IanMiller I would certainly look up the notation $E(X|Y)$ before jumping into these computations, as there may be a shortcut available.

Comment: A [definition](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~ig/MTH5118/Notes5-09.pdf) (from searching google) agrees with your idea: $$\text{Denote } \varphi(y)=E(X|Y=y)\text{. Then }E(X|Y)\overset{\mbox{def}}{=}\varphi(Y).$$ In words, $E(X|Y)$ is a random
variable which is a function of $Y$ taking value $E(X|Y = y)$ when $Y = y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to juggle around a bit with the random variables a bit, then you can solve this without going through all the casses one by one.

First lets split up a bit. Let $U$ denote the sum of the first 4 throws, $V$ the sum of the 5th and 6th throw, and $W$ the sum of the last 4 throws. We then have $X=U+V$ and $Y=V+W$. We also have that $U, V, W$ are independent of each other, and also $U$ being independent of $Y$. We thus already know $E(U|Y)=E(U)=4 \cdot 3.5 = 14$.

Now we can separate
$$ E(X|Y=k) = E(U+V|Y=k) = E(U|Y=k) + E(V|Y=k) = 14+E(V|Y=k)$$.

So we are left to find $E(V|Y=k)$. We can get this by splitting up further: Define $V'$ to be sum of the 7th and 8th throw and $V''$ the sum of the 9th and 10th throw. We then have $Y = V+V'+V''$ and can calculate
$$ E(V|Y=k)+E(V'|Y=k)+E(V''|Y=k)=E(Y|Y=k)=k $$
as we know that if $Y=k$ then certainly $Y=k$.

Now, for symmetry reasons we see that
$$ E(V|Y=k)=E(V'|Y=k)=E(V''|Y=k)$$ 
and thus  $E(V|Y=k)=k/3$. Combining the above we get for every $k$

$$ E(X|Y=k) = 14+E(V|Y=k) = 14 + k/3 $$

and thus

$$ E(X|Y) = 14 + \frac{1}{3}Y.$$

Comment: Empirically counting all $6^{10}$ permutations agrees with $14+k/3$.

Comment: And to express it in the required form, $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)=14+\tfrac 13Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $X_i$ be the outcome of tossing die $i=1,2, \ldots , 12$.
Then
\begin{align}
E(X|Y) & =  E\left( \sum_{i=1}^6 X_i \Big\vert \sum_{i=5}^{10} X_i\right) \\
& =  E\left( X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4 \Big\vert \sum_{i=4}^{10} X_i\right)+E\left( X_5+X_6 \Big\vert \sum_{i=5}^{10} X_i\right)\\
& =  4E(X_i) +E\left( X_5+X_6 \Big\vert \sum_{i=5}^{10} X_i\right) \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i$ denote the value of the $i$-th roll. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(X_1+\cdots+X_6|X_5+\cdots+X_{10})&=&4 E(X_1)+E(X_5+X_6|X_5+\dots+X_{10})\\
&=&4\times7/2+2\times \frac{X_5+\cdots+X_{10}}{6}\\
&=& 14+\frac{X_5+\cdots+X_{10}}{3},
\end{eqnarray*}
where independence was used in the first step and symmetry in the second.

Comment: As the $X_i$ are the same random variable can't you simply it to $14+2X$?

Comment: @IanMiller they are not the same variable, they only have the same distribution.

Comment: Ah yes. Perhaps replace $X_5+\cdots+X_{10}$ with $Y$?

Comment: Indeed,  $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)=14+\tfrac 13 Y$